# What is the bootstrap form-control class for?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having trouble wrapping my brain around the strategy for how to use the `form-control` class offered by Bootstrap.

On one hand I have this rather bland comment from the Bootstrap documentation:

> Textual form controls—like inputs, selects, and textareas—are styled with the .form-control class. Included are styles for general appearance, focus state, sizing, and more.

Ref: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#form-controls

While on the other hand I have rather in-the-weeds code to look at:

```
.form-control {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: $input-height;
  padding: $input-padding-y $input-padding-x;
  // ... 40-some lines elided ...
}
```

ref: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/275cd7f91eed9f4051d85c295e5c14ef08937804/scss/_forms.scss

My question:  How can I holistically approach modifying existing code or writing new code with `form-control`.

Comment: You should not modify Bootstrap classes directly, you should create your own custom classes to override the styles you need

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You add that class to text input elements (input, select, textarea), eg `<input type="email" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="Your email address" />` This is Bootstrap's way of forcing form elements to look the same.

The CSS is so long because they're accounting for all the differences in how browsers natively render those elements.

Comment: Thanks, this is very insightful and helpful.  Any more tips or gotchas I should be aware of?

Comment: @Purplejacket probably but I'm not a heavy Bootstrap user :-) The biggest thing to remember is that all browsers display things slightly differently so somewhere in the range of ~50% of any library like that is creating a baseline.

Answer (score 3):

Bootstrap form-control class is use to make an element fit it container

```
<div>
<input type='text' class='form-control'>
</div>



div{
width: 400px; 
background: gray;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Define a `.form-control` class again. It will override properties in existing `.form-control` of Bootstrap.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
.form-control {
  border-radius: unset;
}
</style>

<input class="form-control" type="text" value="Test">
```